# How long do I need to wait to re-complete a Jumping Puzzle?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have a character parked at the ending chest in the "[Not So Secret](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Not_So_Secret)" Aetherblade jumping puzzle. I logged into the character 1 hour prior to the reset, opened the chest, and switched back to my main character.

3 hours later (2 hours after reset), I switched to the parked character to find the chest was displaying as opened and was non-interactive.

How long do I have to wait to be able to open the chest, again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can confirm that each of the 3 chests in the BL JPs are on separate character-specific 24-hr timers as I’ve made notes of this; for example, if you opened the top-half key chest at 11:00pm and then were attacked/killed and weren’t able to return and retrieve the lower-half key/reward chest until 11:30pm, when you returned the next day at 11:00 pm the top-half key chest would have reset but the lower-half key/reward chest would not reset for another 30 minutes. Server timers have nothing to do with it.

After a quick google search.

[Source](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/gw2/Jumping-Puzzles-Reset-timer)

Comment: Does this mean I could potentially park multiple characters at the same jump puzzle ending and get multiple rewards per day?

Comment: This could possible depend on each jumping puzzle but on first glare i would say yes. You can loot every chest every 24hours per character.

Comment: @Koviko As someone who has done this for a bunch of puzzles, yep.

Comment: @Koviko I currently have 4 characters sitting at the end of the Not So Secret jumping puzzle to get blade shards. It's very convenient if you have character who aren't doing anything in PvE. You can have them visit WvW to use the bank, trading post, merchant, etc if needed, and you can still use them for WvW or PvP, all without moving from the end of the jumping puzzle.

Comment: I hadn't considered that. I just emptied the character's inventory prior to putting them in the Jumping Puzzle. It might be time to make some Blade Shard alts!

Comment: Has ANet ever publicly discouraged this? I would think it's pretty easy to detect someone's account finishing four jumping puzzles in under five minutes. It'd be easy for me to justify logging in for five minutes if I won't be playing that day...